# SSAS Currency Conversion - local Currency

Tags: sql-server, ssas, currency, analysis

Im trying to get local currency as a dimension member in SSAS.

We have a number of facts which all are in one currency (AUD), a currency dimension and an exchange rate fact.

We are using many to many relationships between the facts and the currency dimension with the exchange rate as the intermediate measure group; and measure expressions (measure * exchange rate) to convert the currency.

This all works fine, but I want to add a 'local' currency dimension. Is this possible in this set up?
How can we achieve this?

Comment: What is your goal with "local currency dim", what problem are you going to solve?

Comment: I want to beable to show multiple territories' measures in their own local currency.

Comment: You already have a currency dimension.  Do you mean you want a "local currency" _attribute_ in the Territories/Geography (whatever you call it) dimension?  You could do that with a currency attribute for your territory, and make the Territory dimension slice the exchange rate measure through a referenced or many-to-many relationship.